# Error running tutorial samples in JDBC: UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, jdbc, ant, compilation, versions

**About Me:**

I'm a newer programmer, and not really sure how Apache-Ant works and what it does

---

**Goal:**

Run the sample programs in the [javaconnector jcdb tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)

---

**Platform Background:**

My machine is OSX 10.5.8 32-bit

"`which java`" gives "`/usr/bin/java`", which links to "`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Versions/A/Commands/java`"

"`which javac`" gives "`/usr/bin/javac`", which links to "`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Versions/A/Commands/javac`"

"`echo $JAVA_HOME`" gives a blank line

Java Preferences app in Applications/Utilities lists four versions of Java: 1.6.0_26_b03-385 (64 bit), 1.5.0_30-b03 (32 bit), 1.5.0_30-b03 (64 bit), 1.4.2_22 (32 bit). Currently the 1.6.0 and the two 1.5.0 versions are checked.

NOTE: There is no Java 1.6 for 32-bit OSX 10.5.8

---

**What I Did:**

First I downloaded [connector/j](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j) unpacked it, moved it to `/usr/local/mysql-connector-java`, installed it per the README.txt sections 3.1 and 3.2, including modifying CLASSPATH. I already have and use mysql

Next, I got the ant binary [distribution](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) for version 1.8.4 and installed it according to the [manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html). Notably, the manual states apache ant works with Java 1.5. "`ant -version`" returned the correct version, 1.8.4

Then I  downloaded the [tutorial files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/examples/zipfiles/JDBCTutorial.zip), unzipped the file into a directory, and modified the `build.xml` and `properties/mysql-build-properties.xml` file per the [tutorial's instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html).

Finally I complied the package and samples using "`ant jar`", and created the databases, tables, and populated tables using "`ant create-mysql_database`". I also ran "`ant setup`" for good mesure

According to to the tutorial, I should now be able to run the samples by putting my shell at the tutorial directory and running "`ant <<sample_name>>`" . Therefore, I tried to run the sample suggested by the tutorial, "`ant runct`".

In the middle of this procedure, I never changed which Java I was using in the Java Preferences in Applications/Utilities; I did try the procedure using both 1.5.0_30 and 1.6.0_26 as described below

---

**My Problem:**

After running "`ant <<sample_name>>`" (for example "`ant runct`"), I get the following error:

> Buildfile: /Users/adam/Desktop/JDBCTutorial/build.xml
>
> runct:
>        [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/oracle/tutorial/jdbc/JDBCTutorialUtilities : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 51.0
>        [java]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>        [java]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>        [java]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>        [java]   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>        [java]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>        [java]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>        [java]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>        [java]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>        [java]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>        [java]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>        [java]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>        [java]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>        [java] Java Result: 1
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 1 second

---

**My Attempts at Self-Rectification:**

As far as I can tell from googling, the error has arisen because the files that I downloaded for the tutorial and am attempting to run where compiled with a java other than the one that I am attempting to use to run the files. Therefore, I tried using the 1.6.0 version by putting it at the top of the list in `Applications/Utilities/Java_Preferences`, and confirming it is being used by using "`java -version`", and then executing the above procedure. Same error.

I also tried re-unzipping the tutorial and modifying the .xml files same as above, but changed the `$JAVA` and `$JAVAC` properties in `mysql-sample-properties.xml` to point at files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framwork/Versions/1.5.0/Home/bin`, i.e. a version whose number I know, as opposed to files in "`/usr/bin`", which point to files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framwork/Versions/A/Home/bin`. I then re-ran "`ant jar`", "`ant create-mysql_database`" and "`ant setup`"; from what I understand this should re-compile the .java files using the compiler I specified(correct?). However, I had the same error when I ran "`ant runct`"

I also tried the following, both with re-setting $JAVA and $JAVAC in `mysql-sample-properties.xml` to the default (`i.e. /usr/bin/java and /usr/bin/javac`), and without resetting. I set `$JAVA_HOME` in my .profile to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framwork/Versions/1.5.0/Home`, tested the correct java is used by running `which java` which returned the above path and `java -version` which returned 1.5.0_30, and re-ran "`ant jar`", "`ant create-mysql_database`" and "`ant setup`". When I ran "`ant runct`" I got the same error.

NOTE: The .java files in the tutorial appear to use some objects/syntax added in Java 1.6

A significant problem is I don't know which Java Ant is using.

---

**Additional Questions:**

Why does "`usr/bin/java(c)`" point to version "A"?

What is Java version A???

How do I have a 64-bit java on my 32-bit machine? Is it just emulating a 64-bit machine somehow? If so, does it run slower than 32-bit versions for some tasks?

Why do i have a 64-bit 1.5 Java?

Which Java complier and Java does ant use?

When I change which Java is at the top of the list in `Applications/Utilties/Java_Preferences`, I can confirm that the machine is using the right default Java by doing "java -version", and can check the path of the Java being used by doing "`which java`". Regardless of which Java is at the top of the list i.e. being used, "`which java`" points at "`usr/bin/java`", which is a shortcut to "`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.frameworks/Versions/A/Commands/java`"; this is the same regardless of which version of Java is being used according to `Applications/Utilities/Java_Preferences` and "`java -version`"; how is the machine using different versions of Java while pointing to the same directory/file??

Answer (score 0):

From [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

```
Environment Variables

The wrapper scripts use the following environment variables (if set):

JAVACMD - full path of the Java executable. Use this to invoke a different JVM than JAVA_HOME/bin/java(.exe).
```

So you should have your `JAVA_HOME` set to a correct Java > 1.5 JDK. However its unclear to me which one Ant is using currently since your `JAVA_HOME` is not set. You should uninstall 64bits version of Java if you are on a 32bits system I don't think they can work.

I'm not an OSX expert so I'm also troubled by the full path of your `java`executable, usually it should be in a `bin` folder whose parent is the one you should set for the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable (as explained in the Ant manual). You can search on your system for java executables with `find -name java -perm +x`, maybe you can find a clean java install this way.

Otherwise one of your solutions here is to download a JDK from oracle website, unzip it in a folder like `/opt/java_xxx` and use that as `JAVA_HOME`. Its what I did to have for instance java 6 and 7 side by side on my system.

Comment: jolivier, thank you for the response, but I couldn't get your advice to work. Set $JAVA_HOME in .profile to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framwork/Versions/1.5.0/Home, checked correct java is used by "which java", re-unziped the Tutorial folder and modified the .xml files so .xml properites $JAVA and $JAVAC point to above directory. Same problem. "find ..." didn't work; the command doesn't exist. Can't download a JDK for mac, since mac autoupdate downloads java, and my computer says its fully updated (also there isn't 1.6 for 32bit osx 10.5.8). How do you uninstall versions of Java on osx?

Comment: sorry as I said I dont know OSX and your problem comfort me in refusing it. find is a linux program whose mac equivalent is hard to find (https://www.google.fr/search?q=find+osx+equivalent google has trouble finding find). 
Before running ant are you sure "echo $JAVA_HOME" prints the right thing?

Comment: sorry if i was short :/ I ended giving up on the tutorial, and using the ant files. Learned JDBC off of website tutorials in the end. Thank you anyway :)